# Identifying stocks where the last column in a P&F chart contains three or more "X" plots

Tags: python, mplfinance

First: mplfinance is a super great program for helping with my stock trading: thank you.

Once a week, I download, and use mplfinance to graph the stocks on the S&P 500. I would like to scan the stocks using the P&F charting method and identify the stocks where the last column contains three or more "X" plots without having to physically view each chart. I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks,

Manny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New version (`0.12.7a12`) of mplfinance is now released:

```
pip install --upgrade mplfinance
```

In this version, if you do the following:

```
cv = {}
mpf.plot(df,type=pnf,return_calculated_values=cv)
```

Then the "calculated values" dict, `cv`, will be filled with the following items:

```
dict_keys(['pnf_dates', 'pnf_counts', 'pnf_values', 'pnf_avgvals', 
           'pnf_size', 'pnf_volumes', 'minx', 'maxx', 'miny', 'maxy'])
```

- `cv['pnf_counts']` will contain the number of boxes for each date in `cv['pnf_dates']`.  It will be a positive value for up boxes, X, and a negative value for down boxes, O.
- `cv['pnf_values']` will be a list of lists.  The outer list corresponds to each pnf date, and the inner list at each date corresponds to the *beginning* value of each box on that date: "beginning" means it is the lower bound of an upward box, or the upper bound of a downward box.  For an upward box, the X spans from this value to (value **+** pnf_size), and for a downward box, the O spans from this value to (value **-** pnf_size)
- `cv['pnf_avgvals']` is the average of all pnf_values for a given date, and is the same as `pnf_bricks` that was returned by the previous version of mplfinance.

Hope this helps.  All the best.

Comment: Thanks Daniel: that should do it. Once again, I appreciate the work you have done on mplfinance, I'm sure this work is of great value to the community (including me) and others appreciate it as much as I do.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

When calling `mpf.plot()` use kwarg `return_calculated_values`.  You set this kwarg to an empty dict, and mplfinance will fill it with various calculated values, including the brick values if `type=pnf`:

```py
cv = {}
mpf.plot(df,type=pnf,return_calculated_values=cv)
```

Then look at `cv['pnf_bricks']` and `cv['pnf_dates']`

It should be relatively easy then to scan the list of brick values to find what you want.  You can even create a series out of it to make it easier to manipulate:

```py
pnf_series = pd.Series(cv['pnf_bricks'],index=pd.DatetimeIndex(cv['pnf_dates']))

pnf_series.head()
```

```
2011-07-11 00:00:00+00:00    122.117136
2011-08-08 00:00:00+00:00    114.248562
2011-08-17 00:00:00+00:00    115.232133
2011-08-22 00:00:00+00:00    116.215705
2011-09-01 00:00:00+00:00    117.199277
  dtype: float64
```

```py
pnf_series.tail()
```

```
2011-11-29 00:00:00+00:00    120.149992
2011-12-07 00:00:00+00:00    122.117136
2011-12-20 00:00:00+00:00    129.985711
2012-04-04 00:00:00+00:00    133.919998
2012-06-05 00:00:00+00:00    130.969283
```

Hmmm.  Now that I'm looking at the example I printer out above, perhaps there is a bug in that it appears to be printing out only the **last** **`X`** or **`O`** for each date (not the full list).

Comment: Hello Daniel:

Thanks for the quick response. I'm working through it now. Are the pnf bricks using the ATR?

Once the pnf brick series is created, I must then go through the series and determine if the last three boxes would be calculated as an "X" box (or an "O" box if looking in that direction) for a three box reversal or more: would that be correct?

Thanks,

Manny

Comment: @Manny -- Yes, the default pnf size uses ATR with a length of 14.  But you can pass in other values.  I am looking at the code now.  It appears to me that the value returned for a given date is not the last box, but rather the average of all the boxes on that date *and* the code is *not returning the number of boxs nor the sign*.  That should be fixed.

Comment: Is that a fix you will be working on or is it something I need to figure out?

Thanks,

Manny

Comment: At first glance it seems an easy change.  I will take a break from my current project later today and implement the fix (and see if it's as easy as I think).